# In Excel using VBA or formula, how to generate in single cell a comma-separated list based on complex criteria?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am looking for an Excel formula or VBA solution that generates the result in `Table2` column `Party` based on the data in `Table1` and the inputs in `Table2` column `N`. The inputs in column `N` of `Table2` are numbers corresponding to the order of the rows of data in `Table1`. `Party` in `Table2` should return `ShortName` from `Table`, but if `ShortName` is blank, then `Party` in `Table2` should return `Name`.
Thank you for your help.

Table1

| Name | ShortName |
| --- | --- |
| Jon Doe | Doe |
| Robert Smith |  |
| Susan Miller | SM |
| Donald Duck |  |
| Micky Mouse | The Mouse |
| Kog Enterprises, Inc. | Kog |
| Mechanical, Inc. |  |

Table2

| N | Party |
| --- | --- |
| 1,2,3 | Doe,Robert Smith,SM |
| 4 | Donald Duck |
| 3,5,6 | SM,The Mouse,Kog |
| 2,3,5,6,7 | Robert Smith,SM,The Mouse,Kog,Mechanical, Inc. |

The formula below works, but only for `ShortName`; it does not check `ShortName` and, if blank, default to `Name`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,
INDEX(FILTER(Table1[ShortName],Table1[ShortName]<>""),
MATCH(NUMBERVALUE(TEXTSPLIT([@N2],,",",TRUE,1)),
ROW(Table1[ShortName])-ROW(Table1[[#Headers],[ShortName]]),
0)))
```

The formula below correctly switches between `Name` and `ShortName`, but cannot handle multiple comma-separated values in `Table2` column `N`:

```
IF(INDEX(FILTER(CHOOSE(IF(LOWER(LEFT([@N2],1))="-",1,2),Table3[[Name]:[ShortName]],Table1[[Name]:[ShortName]]),CHOOSE(IF(LOWER(LEFT([@N2],1))="-",1,2),Table3[Name],Table1[Name])<>""),SUBSTITUTE(LOWER([@N2]),"-",""),3)=0,INDEX(FILTER(CHOOSE(IF(LOWER(LEFT([@N2],1))="-",1,2),Table3[[Name]:[ShortName]],Table1[[Name]:[ShortName]]),CHOOSE(IF(LOWER(LEFT([@N2],1))="-",1,2),Table3[Name],Table1[Name])<>""),SUBSTITUTE(LOWER([@N2]),"-",""),1),INDEX(FILTER(CHOOSE(IF(LOWER(LEFT([@N2],1))="-",1,2),Table3[[Name]:[ShortName]],Table1[[Name]:[ShortName]]),CHOOSE(IF(LOWER(LEFT([@N2],1))="-",1,2),Table3[Name],Table1[Name])<>""),SUBSTITUTE(LOWER([@N2]),"-",""),3))
```

The formula above also has other features not discussed here to help keep this post as simple as possible.

Comment: Please update your post with code that you have tried.

Comment: And please explain **in English** the criteria used to determine how the elements of Table1 are allocated to Table2. Don't make us try to figure it out by deciphering your formula, which clearly doesn't work, or you wouldn't be asking in the first place.

Comment: RichardCook, I added this to the post: "The inputs in column N of Table2 are numbers corresponding to the order of the rows of data in Table1." Thank you for your help.

Comment: RichardCook, I added this to the post: "`Party` in `Table2` should return `ShortName` from `Table1`, but if `ShortName` is blank, then `Party` in `Table2` should return `Name`."

Comment: Try: `=ARRAYTOTEXT(XLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(D2,,",")*1,ROW(Table1[ShortName])-1,IF(Table1[ShortName]="",Table1[Name],Table1[ShortName])))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Match Data by Indexes

[image]

- The formula in the 1st row of the *Party* column:

```
=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(", ",,INDEX(IF(
    LEN(Table2[ShortName])>0,Table2[ShortName],Table2[Name]),
        TEXTSPLIT([@N],","))),"")
```

- Excel (structured) tables do not support spilling formulas. Clear the contents of the *Party* column before entering the formula and the whole column will be populated.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative using `ARRAYTOTEXT()` & `XLOOKUP()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `E2`

```
=LET(
    α, Table1[ShortName],
    σ, Table1[Name],
    ARRAYTOTEXT(
        XLOOKUP(
            TEXTSPLIT(
                [@N],
                ,
                ","
            ) * 1,
            ROW(α) - 1,
            IF(α = "", σ, α)
        )
    )
)
```

---

**Note:** Since you have mentioned in your post that you have `Table1` & `Table2` hence spill array formulas won't work with `Structured References`, therefore the above formula needs to be filled down or it will automatically fill down because of `Table Structured` behaviors.

---

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no version constraints as per your tags, the following seems to produce what you describe:

```
F2: =TEXTJOIN(
    ", ",
    TRUE,
    LET(
        r, --TEXTSPLIT(E2, ","),
        f, CHOOSEROWS(Table18, r),
        IF(TAKE(f, , -1) = "", TAKE(f, , 1), TAKE(f, , -1))
    )
)
```

***and fill down***

***Or as a single formula entered only in F2:***

```
=BYROW(
    E2:E5,
    LAMBDA(arr,
        TEXTJOIN(
            ", ",
            TRUE,
            LET(
                r, --TEXTSPLIT(arr, ","),
                f, CHOOSEROWS(Table18, r),
                IF(TAKE(f, , -1) = "", TAKE(f, , 1), TAKE(f, , -1))
            )
        )
    )
)
```

***You can also avoid filling down by setting your output in a `Table`. By entering the formula in the first row of the `Party` column, the formula will fill down automagically.***

[image]